# Google geo chart map: tooltip without region name

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, tooltip

I'm creating a `Google GeoChart Map` and I can customize the tooltip, but I can't seem to get rid of the name of region in it. I'm creating a map of Poland and `Google GeoChart Map` uses `ISO 3166-2` standard for regions and it shows the code of the province in the tooltip which just looks bizarre.

This is the code

```
 function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Województwo');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Frekwencja');
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p:{html:true}}, 'ToolTip');

    data.addRows( [
                  ['PL-DS', 60, '<p>Dolnośląskie</p>60%'],
                  ['PL-KP', 62, '<p>Kujawsko-Pomorskie</p>62%'], 
                  ['PL-LU', 59, '<p>Lubelskie</p>59%'], 
                  ['PL-LB', 61, '<p>Lubuskie</p>61%']
                  ])

    var options = {
        region: 'PL',
        resolution: 'provinces',
        datalessRegionColor: 'transparent',
        displayMode: 'regions',
        tooltip: {
            isHtml: true
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

And I end up with something like this:
[image]

Comment: I don't think that's supported/possible by Google Viz library. It would defeat the purpose of highlighting the selected element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use object notation for data table values
you can provide both the value (`v:`) and formatted value (`f:`)

```
{v: 'PL-DS', f: ''}
```

the tooltip will display the formatted value by default,
supply a blank string to remove it from the tooltip...

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['geochart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Województwo');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Frekwencja');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p:{html:true}}, 'ToolTip');
  data.addRows([
    [{v: 'PL-DS', f: ''}, 60, '<p>Dolnoslaskie</p>60%'],
    [{v: 'PL-KP', f: ''}, 62, '<p>Kujawsko-Pomorskie</p>62%'],
    [{v: 'PL-LU', f: ''}, 59, '<p>Lubelskie</p>59%'],
    [{v: 'PL-LB', f: ''}, 61, '<p>Lubuskie</p>61%']
  ]);

  var options = {
    region: 'PL',
    resolution: 'provinces',
    datalessRegionColor: 'transparent',
    displayMode: 'regions',
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="regions_div"></div>
```

Comment: @WhiteHat Can you share the documentation link where I can learn more about the object notation ?

Comment: sure, you can find it here --> [Format of the Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)